# ASP.NET Chart image is blank except title

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

Im trying to setup a chart control in ASP, just using the built in chart controls.

The way it should work, is when a button is clicked, the page has some tables on it that fill with data, and beside each table is a Scatter-Chart that should populate with data representing that table.  I have the control running through a for statement, adding in a point for each month of the year along with a value for it.  Month being X, value being Y.

I've checked in my debug, the data is there, and the points are listed, but when the page loads, the chart images only displays the Title of the chart, with no graph whatsoever.  I feel like this has something to do with page load, but I'm not sure exactly, nor am I sure how I would incorporate a page load function in.  Or is there a function I can call to render the chart?  I know it isn't an issue with the chart's image location, I tested by placing a point in the ASP markup, displayed that just fine.  But for some reason, it won't display my points I insert on the code-behind.

Code of what I've got so far:

```
<asp:Chart ID="metricsQualityScatter" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"   ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" runat="server" Width="500px" Height="500px">
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Text="Metrics Quality Chart"></asp:Title>
    </Titles>
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="scatterSeries" ChartArea="qualityChartArea" MarkerSize="10" ChartType="Point">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="qualityChartArea"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>


for(int y = 1; y < 13; y++)
{
    switch (y)
    { 
        case 1: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("JAN", yValue; break;
        case 2: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("FEB", yValue; break;
        case 3: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("MAR", yValue; break;
        case 4: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("APR", yValue; break;
        case 5: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("MAY", yValue; break;
        case 6: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("JUN", yValue; break;
        case 7: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("JUL", yValue; break;
        case 8: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("AUG", yValue; break;
        case 9: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("SEP", yValue; break;
        case 10: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("OCT", yValue; break;
        case 11: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("NOV", yValue; break;
        case 12: metricsQualityScatter.Series[0].Points.AddXY("DEC", yValue; break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Ok so I know now it's an issue with the image being created and painted before the data is filled into it.  I tried adding an arguement on my page_load function for If(IsPostBack) using a bunch of checks to make sure that the correct view and button was being pressed to load that data, to try and catch it there, but no dice.  The weird thing is, if I just straight up call the function that fills my data and graphs data from the IsPostBack check, it fills it in fine.  But as soon as I click the actual buttons that is supposed to fill it, we're back to blank.

So, this does NOT work:

```
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string myView = "";
            try
            {
                myView = pageTabs.GetActiveView().ID;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
            if (myView == "metricsDataInputView")
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentCategory.Value))
                {
                    metrics_dataFill(currentCategory.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

But this DOES:

```
if(IsPostBack)
    metrics_dataFill("1");
```

I have no idea why.  I know currentCategory works too, because the tables fill, but the images remain blank.  I think I just need to find a way to repaint the image after filling it with data.  Not sure what to list as the graphic though for that function.

Comment: What is displayChart? How is that initialized cause from what you have posted metricsQualityScatter is the name of the chart control you want to put data in.

Comment: Sorry about that, was cutting a pasting from my code.  displayChart was initialized using a FindControl("metricsQualityScatter") for the div that the charts are under (There are technically 3 charts, each under the same div).  I can just edit it to say metricsQualityScatter, so there's no further confusion.